# Active Admin Translation Missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've translated my app to another language. I've  created ru.yml file with all translations needed in views in it. All worked fine before I go to admin path. I use Active Admin and I've got following error:

> I18n::MissingTranslationData in Admin::Pages#index
>
> translation missing: ru.time.formats.long
>
> insert_tag renderer_for(:index)

How to fix it? I'm interested in both ways: what to do to translate Active Admin too and what to do if I want to keep it in English and just fix the error message.

Answer (score 14):

That was easier than it looked at first. I've just added the following lines to my ru.yml file.

```
time:
 formats:
   long: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently, I've been through the same issue and a quick way to get all default Rails translations set is using the `rails-i18n` gem.

For that you need to add it into your project's `Gemfile` just like this:

```
# Gemfile
...
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

Don't forget after this to run:

```
bundle install
```

I hope this becomes helpful to some other folks in the future.